# How to replace a period with a whitespace but not all whitespaces?

Tags: python, regex, string

How can I replace certain periods with a whitespace but not all of the periods?

For example:

```
this_string = 'Man is weak.So they die'
that_string = 'I have a Ph.d'
```

Here I want to have results like this:

```
this_string = 'Man is weak So they die'
some_string = 'I have a Phd'
```

I want titles like Ph.d to remain as one word while periods that connect 2 sentences be replaced with a space.

---

This is what I have so far:

```
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+',' ', this_string)
```

This would replace all periods with a space.

Any idea how to improve this?

Comment: What is the rule for "certain periods", in your example only the periods between lowercase letters are replaced, is that the rule?

Comment: This is somewhat hard since it requires that your program recognize the meaning of words.

Comment: There isn't exactly a specific rule. It could be between lowercase or uppercases. So Ph.D or Ph.d.

Comment: I think you'd be better off trying to search and replace specific known phrases (e.g. `Ph.D` case-insensitive) than trying to tell the computer to find the difference between `weak.So` and `Ph.D`

Answer (score 0):

You can use two regular expressions as rules to change the text:

```
import re

text = 'Man is weak.So they die. I have a Ph.d.'

text = re.sub(r'([A-Za-z ]{1})(\.)([A-Z]{1})', r'\g<1>. \g<3>', text)  # remove the dot in r'\g<1>. \g<3>' to get '...weak So...'
print(text)  # Man is weak. So they die. I have a Ph.d.

text = re.sub(r'([A-Za-z ]{1})(\.)([a-z]{1})', r'\g<1>\g<3>', text)
print(text)  # Man is weak. So they die. I have a Phd.
```

Finally it's not robust, because it's a rule based transformation. Something like `Ph.D` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could first replace all dots in question with a new symbol and than later split by this symbol:

```
import re

abbreviations = ["Dr.", "Mrs.", "Mr.", "Ph.d"]
rx = re.compile(r'''(?:{})|((?<=[a-z])\.(?=\s*[A-Z]))'''.format("|".join(abbreviations)))

data = "Man is weak.So they die. I have a Ph.d"

# substitute them first
def repl(match):
    if match.group(1) is not None:
        return "#!#"
    return match.group(0)

data = rx.sub(repl, data)
for sent in re.split(r"#!#\s*", data):
    print(sent.replace(".", ""))
```

This yields

```
Man is weak
So they die
I have a Phd
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/LzGtZz).